# PHP preg_replace find a word in string and remove other characters

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am trying to remove from a string all characters that do not match to a list of words.

my list of words could be:

- person
- animal

a string can look like this:

- 123-ea-person.jpg
- 456456-on-Person.jpg
- a-animal-dog.png

my result should look like this:

- person
- person
- animal

my approach:

```php
preg_replace('/(person|animal)/i', '', '123-ea-person.jpg')
```

output:
`123-ea-.jpg`

expected output:
`person`

How can I reverse the pattern to get the result?

Comment: probably a better way, but : https://3v4l.org/nvF2V

Comment: Solution proposed by @Syscall works `preg_replace('/(.*)(person|animal)(.*)/i', '$2$4', '123-ea-person.png');` if you delete extension condition

Comment: @Juan
Yay, this works fine `strtolower(preg_replace('/(.*)(person|animal)(.*)/i', '$2', '123-ea-person.jpg 456456-on-Person.jpg a-animal-dog.png'));`

Comment: How about e.g. [`preg_match('~\b(person|animal)\b~i', $str, $out)`](https://tio.run/##TU3LCoMwELznKxYpRMFI3xdbSm89Cj2qlGhjTKlJSNJb8dfTqJfCsszsPFb32vvTpbgVCK2sMxbOUOLNdkcYJZoZq2T20hyneH84hiFKkuL/TAmVYqBv8lQ805LjOkeoU4bRto@XxusdJpAgANHF2jD@GKgLMh6rJl6efJeWpGpGgdPZH7b6uGSKAbC2VzMv13UWVTLKkfc/)

Comment: What is the desired result if `person` or `animal` occur more than once in the string?

Comment: What is your goal? Are you merely checking for the existence of one of these strings? What if neither exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strtolower` with PCRE verbs could achieve your goal:

```
strtolower(preg_replace('/(?:person|animal)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|./i', '', '123-ea-person.jpg 456456-on-Person.jpg a-animal-dog.png'));
```

with this approach a `person` or `animal` match would be skipped, all other matches would be replaced with nothing.

https://3v4l.org/pZ9YC